# Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Getting this error - "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'FK_transcriptionServiceName' in the referenced table 'transcriptionservices' "

I have searched google to no avail. Any ideas?

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE transcriptionConfig (
  id BIGINT,
  transcriptionEnabled BOOLEAN,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT `FKUSER` FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=ndb;


CREATE TABLE transcriptionServices (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  URL VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=ndb AUTO_INCREMENT=0;


ALTER TABLE transcriptionConfig
  ADD `serviceName` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL;


ALTER TABLE transcriptionConfig
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_transcriptionServiceName
  FOREIGN KEY (serviceName) REFERENCES transcriptionServices(name)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: The transcriptionServices' column name must be a key. (Don't know what that means in MySQL, I'd try to declare it as UNIQUE.)

Comment: Brilliant thanks, changed name to unique as you suggested and it works 100%. `name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE,`